# Cannot find symbol class drawCircle

Tags: java, class, methods, compiler-errors, symbols

So im working on a basic paint program that needs to have a tool that draws a circle. I have created a class named Circle where the actions to do that take place. I am attempting to call the method drawCircle that is inside Circle.class to my Main file. Here is Circle.class

import java.awt.*;
public class Circle {

```
private int x, y, radius;

public Circle(int x, int y, int radius) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.radius=radius;
}
//left/right coordinate for center
public int getx(){
    return x;
}
//up/down coordinate for center
public int gety(){
    return y;
}
//circle's radius(half the diameter)
public int getRadius(){
    return radius;
}
//draws the circle

public void drawCircle(Graphics g){
    Expo.drawCircle(g,x,y,radius);
}

public void setx(int x){
    this.x=x;
}

public void sety(int y){
    this.y=y;
}

public void setRadius(int Radius){
    this.radius=radius;
}
```

}

Now I need to move it to the case structure here (case 5)

```
public void toolClick(Graphics g)
{
    int radius = getRadius(centerX,centerY,rimX,rimY);

    switch(numTools)
    {
        //Pencil Tool
        case 1:
            //Determines the selected size of the pencil tool.
            switch(numSize)
            {
                case 1: Expo.fillCircle(g,xCoord,yCoord,5); break;
                case 2: Expo.fillCircle(g,xCoord,yCoord,15); break;
                case 3: Expo.fillCircle(g,xCoord,yCoord,30); break;
            }
        break;
        //Rectangle Tool
        case 2:
            Expo.drawRectangle(g,x1,y1,x2,y2);
        break;
        //Eraser Tool
        case 3:
            Expo.setColor(g,Colors.white);
            Expo.fillCircle(g,xCoord,yCoord,30);
        break;
        //Line Tool
        case 4:
            Expo.drawLine(g,startX,startY,endX,endY);
        break;
        //Circle Tool(Very Broken)
        case 5:
            Circle tool = new Circle.drawCircle(g); //<-- ERROR!!!!!!!!
            tool.drawCircle(g);
        break;
        //Reset Tool
        case 6:
            Expo.setColor(g,Colors.white);
            Expo.fillRectangle(g,0,81,1000,650);
        break;
        //Fill Tool
        case 7:
            Expo.fillRectangle(g,0,81,1000,650);
        break;
        //Crazy Rectangle tool(not broken)
        case 8:
            Expo.drawRectangle(g,startX,startY,endX,endY);
        break;
        //Crazy Circle tool(not broken)
        case 9:
            Expo.drawCircle(g,centerX,centerY,radius);
        break;
        //Crazy Line tool(not broken)
        case 10:
            Expo.drawLine(g,startX,startY,endX,endY);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get

```
F:\PreAP Computer Science\Paint Program\HashTagTeamPaint.java:278: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class drawCircle
location: class Circle
            Circle tool = new Circle.drawCircle(g);
                                    ^
```

All help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should probably just be

```
   Circle tool = new Circle(startX, startY, 10);
   tool.drawCircle(g);
```

That is, first create a Circle object, then call drawCircle on it. 
You'll need to figure out how pass a radius to the circle too instead
of the hard-coded radius of 10.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much! it worked, and I have already figured out how to get the radius. thank you for your help!